# How can I keep database entries in google cloud firestore private in firebase console even from project owner accounts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to make the cloud firestore database entries for a specific collection private or hidden in firebase console making them unreadable / unaccessible from even the project owner accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add users to your project with different roles (owner, editor or viewer) but it's for the entire project. You cannot add users with custom privilege to access for instance, only a collection or a subcollection.

Comment: Got it, but the owners would always have view access to the entry content correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. What you can do is create a new firestore project and restrict which users have access to that specific project. However, all users on that project will have access to that entire database.